# How to do PostgreSQL '||' operator with knex.update

Tags: postgresql, binding, knex.js

I am working with the following data in table `my_table`:

```
[
  {
    "item": {
      "id": 1,
      "data": {
        "name": "ABC",
        "status": "Active"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "item": {
      "id": 2,
      "data": {
        "name": "DEF",
        "status": "Active"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

I would like to update `name` property of `data`, keeping the rest of `data` intact. A PostgreSQL query for that purpose would look like this:

```
UPDATE my_table SET data = data || '{"name":"GHI"}' WHERE id = 1;
```

However, I am struggling to achieve this with knex, as I've tried:

```
knex('my_table')
.update({ data: knex.raw('data || ?', [{ name: 'GHI' }]) })
.where('id', 1);
```

and many other similar queries, but in vain. If you might have any ideas about this, please share them below. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Using `knex` you indeed have to use raw expressions to update single field inside JSONB column.

However in `objection.js` which is an ORM, built on top of knex, there are some additional support for JSONB operations.

With `objection.js` your update would look like

```
await MyTableModel.query(knex).update({'data:name', 'GHI'}).where('id', 1);
```

Which outputs SQL like this (with bindings ["GHI", 1]):

```
update "my_table" set "data" = jsonb_set("data", '{name}', ?, true) where "id" = ?
```

Runkit example https://runkit.com/embed/0dai0bybplxv